# why does this make calls javascript

Tags: javascript, angular5

Im creating a angular5 application and I have some problems with the services i use to make requests to a simple node backend server. I won't include the backend code because it doesn't matter if it works or not.

My idea was to have the Service remember if it already has the data and if so, don't make another call. I created a boolean called useCache to keep track of whether to make another call. Code shown below.

```
getPeople() {
    console.log('before ', this.useCache);
    if (this.useCache === false) {
      console.log('after', this.useCache);
      this.setPeople(this.api.get(this.url));
      this.useCache = true;
    }
    return this.people;
}
```

useCache is initialized as false so the first time it should make a call.
The second+ times it prints useCache to be true.
This code will not log the ('after', this.useCache) when pressing a button that triggers the GET call multiple times. However my backend server is still registering calls.
people is a undefined variable at first with type any

I tried logging in the api.get function also, and that log isn't printed either.

```
public get(url: string) {
    console.log('get');
    return this.http.get(API_BASE_URL + url).map(response => {
        return response;
    }).catch(this.handleError);
}
```

Inside the component that im calling from i have this function to call the getPeople() function.

```
getPeople() {
    this.personService.getPeople().subscribe(result => {
        console.log(result);
        this.people = result.result;
        this.dataType = 'people';
    });
}
```

Does anyone have any idea how/why my backend is still logging GET calls?
It shouldn't know I pressed that button inside the separate front-end application right?

Comment: Things to try: `return` at the start of the `getPeople` method. See if you still get calls. Remove all the code inside the `if` block. Do you still get calls? What I'm trying to do is confirm whether the calls are coming from some other part of your code.

Comment: @ChrisLear I tried both and no calls are made when adding a return as he first line of getPeople and commenting the current code out and commenting the code inside the if statement does the same. Also these calls are made the people endpoint of my backend (when nothing is commented out)

Comment: if you change return this.people to return static data array of people names does the api call still happen? Could you post the setPeople method?